# Why do DNS queries use loopback interface?

Tags: networking, dns, wireshark, sniffing, loopback

Sniffing (using Wireshark), for didactical purpose, my loopback interface on Ubuntu 12.04, I noticed that a lot of DNS queries (maybe ALL of them) have `127.0.0.1` as source and destination address.

Why?

P.S. I can find the same DNS queries, obviously, on the interface connected to the Internet.

Comment: Do you have dnsmasq installed?

Comment: I have dnsmasq, but I don't know if it's active.

Comment: type in 'sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq status', if it's active, all DNS requests are forwarded to dnsmasq first, if the request is cached you'll get **0 ms** query time, otherwise it gets forwarded to DNS servers, which will get cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications are querying a [local resolver cache](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd), which is then querying a remote resolver. Most likely, the local resolver is implementing a cross-application cache. That way, if two programs both resolve `google.com`, there won't be two remote requests.

Comment: Is it mandatory to query a local cache? Is it possible to query directly a DNS server on the web? I'm asking because I tried to DROP (using `iptables`) all the traffic but that outgoing from the interface connected to the Internet, and doing this I can't use a web browser because it makes DNS queries on local cache.

Comment: Turn off `nscd`. Just stop the service.